# weakly normal filters

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters

Kanamori (Ultrafilters over Uncountable Cardinals) in his Phd Thesis defines a filter $\mathcal F$ as weakly normal whenever every function $f$ such that $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal F$ then there is some $\eta<\kappa$ such that $X=\{\xi<\kappa \mid f(\xi)<\eta\}$ has positive measure (i.e. $X$ has non-empty intersection with every element of $\mathcal F$).

Then he says that weak normality is equivalent to say that every (filter) extension of $\mathcal F$ is weakly normal. But he states it as obvious. I can't find a justification of this.

Comment: Are you sure you got the right definition of weakly normal? In his paper "weakly normal filters and irregular ultrafilters" Kanamori defines weakly normal to mean: If f is regressive on $\mathcal F$ then $f^{-1}[\eta]\in\mathcal F$ for some $\eta<\kappa$ (i.e. this set is _in_ $\mathcal F$ not just of positive measure). Then it is quite clear that what you state is true.

Comment: @user457161 can you tell me where exactly he says that?

Comment: @user457161i've read this paper and he never states $f^{-1}[\eta]\in\mathcal F$

Comment: In Definition 1.1 he defines in $(v)$ that $\mathcal F$ is weakly normal iff every function that is regressive on a set in $\mathcal F$  is not unbounded (mod $\mathcal F$). In $(i)$, he states that $f:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$ is unbounded iff for all $\eta<\kappa$, $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid f(\alpha)>\eta\}$ has positive $\mathcal F$-measure. In other words, $f$ is not unbounded, if there is $\eta$ so that $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid f(\alpha)\leq\eta\}\in \mathcal F$. Putting these two together, we get the definition I mentioned above.

Comment: @user457161 If $f$ is bounded then there is some $\eta$ such that $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)\leq \eta\}$ has positive measure. I don't see how you can deduce $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)\leq \eta\}\in\mathcal F$ (if $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter we can do this, but then the equivalence becomes trivial since there are no extensions)

Comment: If $f$ is nounded then there is even come $\eta$ so that $\{\xi<\kappa\vert f(\xi)\leq\eta\}\in\mathcal F$ and not just of positive measure. If $f$ is unbounded, this means that $\forall\eta<\kappa\ \{\xi<\kappa\vert f(\xi)>\eta\}$ is of positive $\mathcal F$-measure. Now for $f$ to _not_ be unboudnded, there is some $\eta$ so that $A=\{\xi<\kappa\vert f(\xi)>\eta\}$ is _not_ of positive $\mathcal F$ measure. Thus there is $X\in\mathcal F$ with $X\cap A=\emptyset$. Hence $X\subseteq\{\xi<\kappa\vert f(\xi)\leq\eta\}\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: @user457161 You are more than right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user457161 Wait, i think there may be a flaw. I am not sure, but assume $\mathcal F$ is  weakly normal and let $\mathcal D\supset\mathcal F$. To prove $\mathcal D$ is weakly normal take $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ regressive modulo $\mathcal D$ i.e. $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal D$. How can i be sure that $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal F$?? We do now that $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}$ has positive measure. But (according to the definition) having positive measure isn't enough to state that $f$ is bounded modulo $\mathcal F$.

Comment: From $f$ you can pass to $f^\prime$ which is regressive everywhere and coincides with $f$ on a set in $D$. Just let $f^\prime$ be 0 outside of $\{\alpha<\kappa\vert f(\alpha)<\kappa\}$. Then you can apply the weak normality of $\mathcal F$ to $f^\prime$. You can carry this over to see that $f$ is bounded w.r.t. $\mathcal D$ using that $f=f^\prime$ on a set in $\mathcal D$.

Comment: @user457161 I am not convinced with this argument. If $f'$ is defined as you say, then $f=f'$, because $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid f(\alpha)<\kappa\}=\kappa$. On the other hand, if we define $g$ as $f(\alpha)$ for $alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ and 0 elsewhere, we still cannot state that $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid \alpha<g(\alpha\}\in\mathcal F$. We can only state positive measure.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want to say. The $f^\prime$ I had in mind is exactly the $g$ that you defined and it is (in general) not true that $f=f^\prime$. Clearly we have $\{\alpha<\kappa\vert \alpha=0\vee\alpha<g(\alpha)\}=\kappa\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: To complete the proof: Since $g$ is regressive everywhere, we can apply the weak normality of $\mathcal F$. This gives a $\eta<\kappa$ so that $\{\alpha<\kappa\vert g(\alpha) <\eta\}\in\mathcal F$. The same $\eta$ works for $f$ with respect to $\mathcal D$. To see this, let $A=\{\alpha<\kappa\vert f(\alpha)<\alpha\}\in\mathcal D$. We have $\{\alpha<\kappa\vert f(\alpha)<\eta\}\supseteq A\cap \{\alpha<\kappa\vert g(\alpha)<\eta\}\in\mathcal D$ and hence $\{\alpha<\kappa\vert f(\alpha)<\eta\}\in\mathcal D$ as well.

Comment: Let $\mathcal D\supset\mathcal F$ be a filter over $\kappa$. To prove that $\mathcal D$ is weakly normal, take $f:\kappa\to kappa$ with $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal D$.$X=\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}$ ONLY HAS POSITIVE MEASURE W.R.T $\mathcal F$. If we define $g:\kappa\to$ as $g(\xi)=f(\xi)$ for $\xi\in X$ and $0$ elsewhere, then $\{\xi<\kappa\mid g(\xi)<\xi\}$ DOES NOT BELONG TO $\mathcal F$, but has positive measure modulo $\mathcal F$. What i am trying to say is that Kanamori's definition does not works to prove this unless we ask $\{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal F^+$

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that $\{\xi<\kappa\vert g(\xi)<\xi\}\notin\mathcal F$? This set is clearly equal to $\kappa\setminus\{0\}$ and thus in $\mathcal F$!

Comment: @user457161 $\{\xi<\kappa\mid g(\xi)<\xi\} = \{\xi<\kappa\mid f(\xi)<\xi\}\in\mathcal D$, if $f$ is regressive everywhere, in $[1,\kappa)$, then $g$ will also be regressive everywhere. But what if $f$ is regressive over some $X\in\mathcal D\setminus \mathcal F$? Then we cannot be certain that $g$ is regressive on a set of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: No, $\{\xi<\kappa\vert g(\xi)<\xi\} \neq \{\xi<\kappa\vert f(\xi)<\xi\}$! (in general). We have defined $g$ exactly to have $g$ regressive _everywhere_ so in particular on a set in $\mathcal F$. Thats the whole point of defining $g$.

Comment: @user457161 Sorry if i have been so pushy, i just wasn't convinced by the arguments but you are more than right